# Junk Characters Outputted After Parsing From STDIN in C

Tags: c, io, stdin

I am getting a junk character to be output at the very end of some text that I read in:

```
hum 1345342342 ~Users/Documents ecabd459 //line that was read in from stdin
event action: hum_?
event timestamp: 1345342342
event path: ~Users/Documents
event hash: ecabd459
```

At the end of the event action value there is a '_?' garbage character that is output as well. That can be rectified by setting the variable's last position to the null terminator (`event.action[3] = '\0'`) which is all well and good, but I am perplexed by the fact that the other char array `event.hash` does not exhibit this type of behavior. I am creating/printing them in an identical manner, yet hash does not behave the same.

**Note:** I was considering maybe this was due to the hash value being followed strictly by a newline character(which I get rid of by the way), so I tested my program with re-ordered input to no avail (that is, added an additional space and word after the hash value's position on the line).

The relevant code is below:

```
struct Event{
    char action[4];
    long timestamp;
    char* path;
    char hash[9];
};   

// parse line and return an Event struct
struct Event parseLineIntoEvent(char* line) {
    struct Event event;
    char* lineSegment;

    int i = 0;
    lineSegment = strtok(line, " ");
    while (lineSegment != NULL) {
        if (i > 3) {
            printf("WARNING: input format error!\n");
            break;
        }
        if (i == 0)
            strncpy(event.action, lineSegment, sizeof(event.action)-1);
        else if(i == 1)
            event.timestamp = atoi(lineSegment);
        else if(i == 2) {
            event.path = malloc(sizeof(lineSegment));
            strcpy(event.path, lineSegment);
        } else if(i == 3)
            strncpy(event.hash, lineSegment, sizeof(event.hash)-1);
        lineSegment = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    } // while
    return event;
} // parseLineIntoEvent()

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//...
    printf("%s\n",line); //prints original line that was read in from stdin
    struct Event event = parseLineIntoEvent(line);
    printf("event action: %s\n", event.action);
    printf("event timestamp: %lu\n", event.timestamp);
    printf("event path: %s\n", event.path);
    printf("event hash: %s\n", event.hash);
    free(event.path);
    free(line);
//...
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I read in a line with this function, which gets rid of the newline character:

```
// read in line from stdin, eliminating newline character if present
char* getLineFromStdin() {
    char *text;
    int textSize = 50*sizeof(char);
    text = malloc(textSize);

    if ( fgets(text, textSize, stdin) != NULL ) {
        char *newline = strchr(text, '\n'); // search for newline character
        if ( newline != NULL ) {
            *newline = '\0'; // overwrite trailing newline
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get rid of the newline?

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I am perplexed by the fact that the other char array event.hash does not exhibit this type of behavior

You got unlucky. hash[8] may have gotten a '\0' by sheer (bad-)luck.

Try setting it to something "random" before your strtok loop

```
    int i = 0;
    event.hash[8] = '_';             /* forcing good-luck */
    lineSegment = strtok(line, " ");
    while (lineSegment != NULL) {
```

Comment: Yeah, now I am getting: `event hash: ecabd459_` This is because event.hash was set to all '_' characters and I didn't overwrite the last one, correct?

Comment: Neither `event.action` nor `event.hash` were initialized, so they happen to contain garbage. In the case of `event.action` that garbage makes it not a string (it's UB to print it with "%s") and printf accesses memory areas that it shouldn't (`event.action[4]` and more). By setting `event.hash[8]` to `'_'` the same happens to this variable. Unluckly, the unexistent *`event.hash[9]`* appears to be a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a mistake:

```
event.path = malloc(sizeof(lineSegment));
```

will return the `sizeof(char*)`, when you require the length plus one for terminating NULL character:

```
event.path = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(lineSegment) + 1));
```

To avoid having to insert null string terminators into `action` and `hash` you could initialise `event`:

```
struct Event event = { 0 };
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char) == 1` is explicitly guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: Thanks for those tips. Worked well and that struct initialization tip is a very elegant fix to my problem. Have any ideas for the discrepancy I am witnessing?

Comment: @Stunner, sorry, what is the discrepancy?

Comment: @hmjd I am getting junk characters after the output for `event.action`, but not `event.hash` which are constructed in the same way, only difference is the sizes differ.

Comment: @hmjd Oh, no no, your last suggestion fixed my issue. But I am still curious as to why this behavior occurred. So far pmg's post is the only one that directly attempts to explain why this occurs. I am just trying to get at least a secondary opinion before accepting an answer. Thanks!

Comment: There are no guarantees as to what uninitialized memory contains, so you may have got "lucky" and `hash[8]` contained a NULL.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

```
The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.
Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string
placed in dest will not be null-terminated.
```

When doing `strncpy` you have to make sure the destination string is properly terminated.

Change the setting of the `event.action` field:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    strncpy(event.action, lineSegment, sizeof(event.action)-1);
    event.action[sizeof(event.action)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the nice way of fixing the issue, but why doesn't the same thing happen to the hash character array I did the same thing with? I use `strncpy` with that too...

Comment: @Stunner Yes, it applies to all calls to `strncpy`; If you are unsure, manually terminate the string.

Comment: I'd omit the `-1` from the size passed to `strncpy`. It doesn't matter much, because whether or not `strncpy` writes the last character, it will be overwritten by '\0'. But in general, passing sizeof(buf) to strnxxx functions is a good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the string "num" takes only three elements from the 4 element character array Event.action and the fourth element will stay unset. Because nothing has been set to the Event.action array element it will point to random memory location which has some random value stored. When you printf this character array it will print all of the elements instead of those pointing to valid data. This causes the garbage character to show up.